# Sent two models to a view with Sequelize

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I tried to send two models to a view with Sequelize but I don't know how to proceed.

My code below doesn't work.

```
Post.findAll().success( function(posts) {
    Creation.findAll().success( function(creations) {
        res.render('admin_index', {
            creations: creations,
            posts: posts
        });
    });
});
```

Anthony

Comment: what issue do u experience?

Comment: Array "posts" isn't recognized in my view "admin_index"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you arent returning any posts in your callback and that's why posts is undefined.

So that you cant access it in yoru res.render context.

Check this part of your callback

```
 Creation.findAll().success( function(creations) {
    // The other stuff
});
```

Here you are only returning creations instead you should write a query that returns both creations and posts. Or do multiple queries in a callback chain something like these.

```
 RandomQuery.findAll().success( function(creations,posts) {
    // The other stuff
});
```

Or chain the callbacks inside each other

```
 Creation.findAll().success( function(creations) {
    Post.findAll().success(function(posts){

        res.render('admin_index', {
            creations: creations,
            posts: posts
        });  

    });
});
```

Comment: Thank's, it works! I had forgot to switch "creations" and "posts".